# getting item width, height and margin and rounding those values

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use jquery to make Google Chrome use whole figure values for element widths, heights and margins? I am setting them as % in CSS - but would like Chrome to behave like Firefox and round them up/down to make whole figures...

So CSS is:

```
.example {
width: 33.3%;
height: 19.5%;
margin: 0.1%;
}
```

And when Chrome renders this - it renders with values like below:

```
<div class="example" style="width: 33.456px; height: 18.123px; margin: 0.054px;"></div>
```

What I want it to become is:

```
<div class="example" style="width: 33px; height: 18px; margin: 1px;"></div>
```

So each value is rounded up/down
Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, can you please be more clear

Comment: Just updated answer with some more context

Comment: This sure must help @Help

Comment: It still isn't clear, if you have class then how come you are getting `in-line` styles ? can please create a fiddle for it ?

Comment: If you inspect the element, is it __actually__ rendered at the decimal width? Chrome might show it as decimals in the DOM but I'm fairly sure they're rounded when it comes to display. No browser can render parts of pixels. Bear in mind too this is CSS pixels, not screen pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do it, but you can use Javascript/jquery for it:

You can get element width and height with jquery like this:

```
var width = $(".example").width();
var height = $(".example").height();
```

Then use e.g. round/ceil method from javascript to get the rounded values.
To set width and height use jquery width()/height() method again.